# Can't access hidden inputbox value from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to extract a value from my hidden inputbox, by using javascript, but sometimes i am getting a "undefined" error and sometimes no output.
   when i did

```
alert(document.getElementById('hhh').value);
```

from inside a printIt() function i get the output. but i think somehow it is not going in to "var a", and also

```
var a =22;
```

works if i remove the

```
var a =document.getElementById('hhh').value;
```

in below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a =document.getElementById('hhh').value;
function startTime()
{

document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=a;
a=a-1;
t=setTimeout('startTime()',600);
}
</script>

<body    onLoad="startTime()">
<form name="form1"   id="form11" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="hhh" name="time" value="11" />
</form>
<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, pass functions instead. And don't use `setTimeout` for something you want to keep happening, use `setInterval` instead. `setInterval(startTime, 600);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var a =document.getElementById('hhh').value;`

This runs before the document is loaded so the underlying element may not exist in the DOM.

You call `document.getElementById('hhh')` before `hhh` exists. Move it into a function you call `onload`.

```
var a;
function setup() {
    a = document.getElementById('hhh').value;
    startTime();
}
function startTime() {
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = a--;
    setInterval(startTime, 600);
}
```

and run `setup();` in your onload.

Comment: so how can i make it accessible without including it in the startTime(), as it won't get decremented then

Answer (score 4):

You call `document.getElementById('hhh')` before `hhh` exists. Move it into a function you call `onload`.

Comment: if i move there, my var a will not get decremented.

Comment: In onload call a new function that does your setup - reading `a` etc then have it call `setInterval(startTime,600);`

Answer (score 2):

Leave it as an "type=input" and add the css property: `display: none;`

```
<input type="input" id="hhh" name="time" value="11" style="display: none;" />
```